# Reboot Into Command Line - SSH

Tags: boot, command-line, drivers, grub2, ssh

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04

I am working on my machine remotely via SSH - I am trying to install some ATI drivers for my graphics card however I need to run the installation without an X server running in order to complete the installation.

Will I need to manually edit the grub.cfg to boot into the command line?  I have no access to the boot menu as I am using SSH.

Comment: Why do you need to reboot, specifically? Wouldn't it be simpler to just kill  the X server (or stop the display manager)?

Comment: I think `sudo service lightdm stop` should be sufficient.

Comment: you do have acces to reboot. use sudo reboot, when asked for root password, enter root password and your system will be rebooted

Comment: Maybe you want to bring the machine to runlevel 3: `sudo telinit 3` (http://centoshelp.org/resources/post-install-options/changing-runlevels)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies.  I think sudo telinit 3 will do the trick

Comment: @glennjackman may as well post that as an answer.